# How to upload videos from Blender to Youtube (and other things)

Tags: video

Yes, I have checked the other threads. Yes, I looked at the online tutorials. Yes, I tried converting it to an AVI file, but instead of getting what I want, I got either a very slowed down version of my video with no audio, or one with normal speed except my video is only 3 seconds long.

I even downloaded ffmpeg to try to "convert" the video, but I can't find any of the saved copies of my videos that I have.

I posted some of my settings down here.

Also, the video is showing up on a weird 90 degree tilt. So, how do I rotate it?

(from the .AVI one, to the .blender one, to the five other formats that I tried saving it under).

[image]

Comment: I find the "FFMpeg Video" with the Encoding -> Audo set to AAC works best. Uploaded a simple video using that to YouTube a few days ago without issue.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several problems in your project:

1. File format is not the right one for YouTube
2. The frame rate is set to 32767
3. The camera might be rotated by 90°

Regarding 1): You probably want to use `FFmpeg video` as output format, with the *Container* set to `MPEG-4`, *Video Codec* set to `H.264` and *Audio Codec* to `AAC`. This will create a lossy compressed video file. This seems to be one of the standard configurations that [YouTube recommends](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4603579?hl=en).

Regarding 2): The frame rate should likely be 24/25/30/60 fps depending on the speed of your animation and the desired output frame rate.

Regarding 3): It could be that your camera is rotated 90° or it's because another setting in the video export was causing the issue. Check in the viewport that the camera perspective is correct by pressing <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

Comment: I did number one, but the the video is still only half the speed. Also, by "frame rate should likely be 24/25/30/60 fps depending on the speed of your animation and the desired output frame rate" do I just go under frame rate and change it to one of those numbers? I only see one unit, instead of 4, units in which I can divide that ratio into. And, sorry, I  don't know what you mean by "viewport", this entire app is just one big Gordian knot to me.